# How to use templates instead of macros to create a class with a dynamic number of functions

Tags: c++, function, templates, dynamic, macros

Currently i am creating a base class with set and get functions with a macro.
But I would like to add more complex macros but macros are really bad for debugging so I would like to do it with templates but I have no idea does someone know a book or link for me.

My real problem is far more complex I just created a set and get example to demonstrate the problem.

As an simple example see:

```
#include <iostream>

#define SETGET_BEGIN(name) \
  class name##Base { \
  public: name##Base(){};

#define SETGET_VAR(type,name) \
  protected: type name##_; \
  public: void set##name(const type &_r) {name##_ = _r;} ; \
  public: const type &get##name() const {return name##_; };  \

#define SETGET_END };

SETGET_BEGIN(MyClass)
SETGET_VAR(int,NrA)
SETGET_VAR(float,NrB)
SETGET_END

class MyClass : public MyClassBase {
  public: 
    MyClass() : MyClassBase() {};
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MyClass myclass;
    myclass.setNrA(4);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: templates are not a replacement for macros, they serve an entirely different purpose.

Comment: You don't need semicolons (`;`) after your constructor/method declarations.

Comment: By template you can only set types of your class members/functions. You cannot set names. So the answer is: you cannot do it by templates.

Comment: Having both get and set is usually a design mistake. Why do you need them?

Comment: Not related to your question: I think a design by which you make many member variables not only `protected` but also accessible using public getters and setters is quite questionable. There's basically no encapsulation at all, you may just as well inherit from a `struct` with two public fields.

Comment: One sticking point here is that a class template cannot have members whose names are the result of token-pasting (`NrA_` and `set_NrA`). Templates can take types as template arguments, but not a sequence of tokens like macros do. So you cannot use templates simply to reproduce these macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine different types of setters and getters using template mixins. Template mixins define a class that inherits from its template parameter. Here's your example using mixins instead of macros:

```
class MyBaseClass {
public:
    MyBaseClass() {}
};

template<class B> class SetGetNrA : public B {
private:
    int NrA;
public:
    void setNrA(int NrA) { this->NrA = NrA; }
    int getNrA() { return NrA; }
};

template<class B> class SetGetNrB : public B {
private:
    float NrB;
public:
    void setNrB(float NrB) { this->NrB = NrB; }
    float getNrB() { return NrB; }
};
```

Now to use it:

```
typedef SetGetNrA<SetGetNrB<MyBaseClass> > MyClass;
MyClass myclass;
myclass.setNrA(4);
```

You could make the type of the variable a template parameter as well, but you'll have to use macros if you want the name of the variable to be a parameter. Still, doing more of the work in templates ensures you'll get better error messages from a nice compiler (clang++) than you would with just macro substitution.

Answer (score 3):

Even though macro's are not the greatest feature of C++, because of scope issues, debugging limitations and other possible surprises, they do have their occasional use.  One of their strengths, because macro's are text replacers, is the possibility to create code using text-input as done in your example.

I don't see the added value of your approach to making "dynamic" classes, but a similar approach might be usable for serialization or value checking of enum-values or other repeating code.  Macro's can also be used for logging to get the filename/linenumber/functionname/...

So, as already commented by Gumik, I don't see how you can do this with templates.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is `std::tuple`. It contains all the functionality you need, except for the names. Instead of `setnrA(int)` the tuple method will be `set<1>(int)`. Obviously you can add an enum to assign meaningful names to the tuple indices, so you can call `.set<nrA>(4)`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to pay a look at the book "Modern C++ Design:
Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied". Specifically the "PolicyBased Class Design" chapter may give you some ideas.
I don't know if it will match your exact needs, though.